# How can I keep record of changes after an update in a table in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, csv

Im importing a csv file into a sql table, from there it is ok. Im also updating a column called date, so everytime an user import a file it also updates the date. But the problem is that the user needs to upload a file every month and I need to keep track of every upload into the table. I do not know how to do it. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Triggers can be useful for logging.

Comment: So instead of updating, add a new record with every upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know changes in the file you can just use a column with an update date (you can use triggers for this or edit your column like:  `` `tm` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ``). You could also store a number of "edit times" to see if it's the same as the number of months since the creation of the row.
Otherwise, you should write a new row for every update and keep track of the user by an ID.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Now I have a trigger after update, but as you say I need to know changes in the file, there is one column with an employee discount that is changing every month, so for example when I need to do a query about the three past months' discount and verify they are not null, I do not know how to do it. New problem to solve.

Comment: Ok, so if you can still change tables in DB, probably the best way is having a table for employee with an id and all references (plus the column with update) and an other one used like a "log table" where you store all rìchanges updates etc keeping track of employee id